# mousewheel smooth scroll с анимацией фигур

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Есть такой код:

```js
var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax', {
  center: false,
  wrapper: null,
  round: true,
  vertical: true,
  horizontal: false
});


// TweenMax
$(function() {

  var $window = $(window); //Window object

  var scrollTime = 1.2; //Scroll time
  var scrollDistance = 170; //Distance. Use smaller value for shorter scroll and greater value for longer scroll

  $window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 || -event.originalEvent.detail / 3;
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var finalScroll = scrollTop - parseInt(delta * scrollDistance);

    //console.log(finalScroll);

    $('.leaf>img').css({
      'transform': 'rotateX(0deg)'
    });
    //$('.leaf>img').removeClass('rotate');

    TweenMax.to($window, scrollTime, {
      scrollTo: {
        y: finalScroll,
        autoKill: true
      },
      ease: Power1.easeOut,
      autoKill: true,
      overwrite: 5,
      onComplete: function() {
        $('.leaf>img').css({
          'transform': 'rotateX(50deg)'
        });
        //$('.leaf').addClass('rotate');
      }
    });

  });

});

// MouseWheel
// if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
// window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

// function wheel(event) {
//     var delta = 0;
//     if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 220;
//     else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

//     handle(delta);
//     if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
//     event.returnValue = false;
// }

// var goUp = true;
// var end = null;
// var interval = null;

// function handle(delta) {
//  var animationInterval = 20; //lower is faster
//     var scrollSpeed = 20; //lower is faster

//  if (end == null) {
//    end = $(window).scrollTop();
//   }
//   end -= 20 * delta;
//   goUp = delta > 0;

//   if (interval == null) {
//     interval = setInterval(function () {
//       var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
//       var step = Math.round((end - scrollTop) / scrollSpeed);
//       if (scrollTop <= 0 || 
//           scrollTop >= $(window).prop("scrollHeight") - $(window).height() ||
//           goUp && step > -1 || 
//           !goUp && step < 1 ) {
//         clearInterval(interval);
//         interval = null;
//         end = null;
//       }
//       $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop + step );
//     }, animationInterval);
//   }
// }
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

main {
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.leaf {
  display: block;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 20vw;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;
}


/* .rotate {
  animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out;
}


@keyframes rotate {
  from { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
  50% {transform: rotateX(50deg);}
  to { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
} */

.l-2 {
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.l-3 {
  margin-left: 70%;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -10%;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rellax/1.7.1/rellax.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>

<header id="scene">

  <span data-rellax-speed="-2" data-rellax-percentage="0.5" class="rellax leaf l-1">
    <img src="https://pics.clipartpng.com/midle/Leaf_PNG_Clip_Art-1968.png" alt="" >
  </span>

  <span data-rellax-speed="-3" data-rellax-percentage="0.5" class="rellax leaf l-2">
    <img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/20180201/pye/kisspng-maple-leaf-clip-art-maple-leaf-5a72a608f0a8c5.3016083115174630489858.png" alt="" >
  </span>

  <span data-rellax-speed="-1" data-rellax-percentage="0.75" class="rellax leaf l-3">
    <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-leaf-png-9.png" alt="" >
  </span>

</header>
<main>
  <h1>Smooth Scroll</h1>
  <h2>Use your mousewheel to scroll</h2>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur natus, facere nulla similique doloremque! Ullam voluptatem debitis esse. Deleniti quas, vel ad consectetur facilis ab consequatur voluptate aut optio odit nisi reprehenderit sint, ipsa
    incidunt itaque id voluptatum repudiandae alias esse velit quo voluptatibus recusandae earum eligendi! Est, quae, aliquam?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, earum ullam hic id! Corporis cupiditate, voluptatibus eligendi suscipit ratione eos, sequi aperiam voluptatem laboriosam! Debitis consectetur eum aperiam similique ullam dolore, labore
    porro, sequi fuga atque, tempora, est delectus veniam! Ad tempora, voluptas cupiditate praesentium illo iure. Cupiditate, necessitatibus natus id eius nulla ab suscipit tempora nisi itaque omnis quas, voluptates accusantium cum labore nam. Laboriosam
    alias doloremque quos adipisci pariatur ipsum doloribus et cupiditate omnis cum, ducimus deleniti, sequi optio harum! Iste quas in, qui nobis voluptatibus quibusdam doloremque culpa, numquam officia incidunt, quidem! Asperiores omnis amet incidunt
    eveniet.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium animi sint officiis, voluptate nam vitae inventore minus aliquid temporibus soluta natus, qui repellendus ducimus eum veritatis neque impedit odio quibusdam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur natus, facere nulla similique doloremque! Ullam voluptatem debitis esse. Deleniti quas, vel ad consectetur facilis ab consequatur voluptate aut optio odit nisi reprehenderit sint, ipsa
    incidunt itaque id voluptatum repudiandae alias esse velit quo voluptatibus recusandae earum eligendi! Est, quae, aliquam?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, earum ullam hic id! Corporis cupiditate, voluptatibus eligendi suscipit ratione eos, sequi aperiam voluptatem laboriosam! Debitis consectetur eum aperiam similique ullam dolore, labore
    porro, sequi fuga atque, tempora, est delectus veniam! Ad tempora, voluptas cupiditate praesentium illo iure. Cupiditate, necessitatibus natus id eius nulla ab suscipit tempora nisi itaque omnis quas, voluptates accusantium cum labore nam. Laboriosam
    alias doloremque quos adipisci pariatur ipsum doloribus et cupiditate omnis cum, ducimus deleniti, sequi optio harum! Iste quas in, qui nobis voluptatibus quibusdam doloremque culpa, numquam officia incidunt, quidem! Asperiores omnis amet incidunt
    eveniet.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium animi sint officiis, voluptate nam vitae inventore minus aliquid temporibus soluta natus, qui repellendus ducimus eum veritatis neque impedit odio quibusdam.
  </p>
</main>
```

Страничка с плавным скроллом. [Листочки с parallax эффектом](https://github.com/dixonandmoe/rellax).

Для плавного скролла пытаюсь использовать или mousewheel или вот рабочий вариант с tweenMax (пока не могу выбрать какой вариант лучше).

При параллаксе листочков динамически генерируется необходимый `transform:translate3d(...)`.

Хотелось бы чтобы при остановке скролла анимация поворота листочка начиналась как-то только остановили скроллить колесико (в этот момент еще неторое время стр. скроллится сама по анимации).

Пример [brontidebg.com](https://www.brontidebg.com/), все то же самое хотелось бы, но намного проще с jquery.

**Вопрос:**

Как начать анимацию листиков (поворот `rotateX(...`) сразу после окончания скролла колесиком мыши, т.е. чтобы поворот фигуры совпадал с "доскролливанием" (по анимации) стр.  ? Получается какое-нибудь событие за секунду до `onComplete`.

Comment: Окей, что если анимация уже началась по "завершению вращения колесика", а пользователь опять начал крутить? Что если он крутит очень медленно, по тику в секунду?

Comment: @yolosora, пример https://www.brontidebg.com/

Comment: с телефона кстати выглядит невероятно убого)

Comment: @yolosora, меня не интересует телефон! Только десктоп!

Answer (score 3):

Получилось реализовать подобный эффект с помощью [jquery.parallax-scroll](http://free.matthieu.com/jquery.parallax-scroll/demo.html)

```js
function elements () {
    $('.element1 img').css('opacity', 0).one('inview', function(isInView) {
        if (isInView) {$(this).addClass('animated fadeInRight delayp7');}
    });

    $('.element2 img').css('opacity', 0).one('inview', function(isInView) {
        if (isInView) {$(this).addClass('animated fadeInRight delayp8');}
    });
}

elements();


$(window).scroll(function () {
    var ww = $(window).width();
  
  elements();
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.element {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}

.element.element2 {
    width: 85px;
    margin-left: 34px;
    top: 54px;
  }

.element.element4 {
    width: 85px;
    margin-left: -154px;
    top: 24px;
  }

.element.element1 {
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -69px;
    top: 72px;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1500px;
}

.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}


.delayp7 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}

.delayp8 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.4s;
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" />
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/protonet-jquery.inview/1.1.2/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://live.skillbox.ru/pagerevo/revodec/js/vendor/jquery.parallax-scroll.js"></script>
  
<section>
  <div class="element element1" data-parallax='{"y": 300, "from-scroll": 20, "smoothness": 20, "distance": 200, "scaleY":0.5}'>
    <img src="https://pics.clipartpng.com/midle/Leaf_PNG_Clip_Art-1968.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="element element2" data-parallax='{"y": 250, "from-scroll": 40, "smoothness": 20, "distance": 100, "scaleY":0.65}'>
    <img src="https://png2.kisspng.com/20180201/pye/kisspng-maple-leaf-clip-art-maple-leaf-5a72a608f0a8c5.3016083115174630489858.png" alt="">
  </div> 
  
  <div class="element element4" data-parallax='{"y": 510, "x": -120, "from-scroll": 30, "smoothness": 20, "distance": 200, "scaleY":0.55}'>
    <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/green-leaf-png-9.png" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```